# Set cursor position using setSelection on AutoCompleteTextView which is dynamically generated

Tags: android

I am working on a project which uses a TableLayout, and the user can add a new row to the table layout. Each new row is inflated as a new view and then the view is added to the table layout. One of the controls within the row is an AutoCompleteTextView.

The user can start typing into the AutCompleteTextView and then select one of the items in the suggestion list, when the user selects the item, the selected item is added to the text box as expected, but I want to then set the cursor position as the user can then change the value of the text. For example, the selected item might be `sometext()` but they can amend the text after selecting it to become `sometext(25)`, so I am trying to set the position of the cursor within the brackets.

This is working fine for one AutoCompleteTextView in the layout but I can't figure out how to do it when its dynamically generated.

I'm finding the AutoCompleteTextView from the inflated layout and creating a set on item click listener, and using the `view` parameter in the OnItemClick function to ensure I am using the correct view that triggered the event handler, but on the setSelection I am getting an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView`

Below is the code I am using:

```
private void addRow()
    {
        TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.create_table_column_row, createTable, false);
        txtColumnName = row.findViewById(R.id.txtColumnName);
        txtDataType = row.findViewById(R.id.txtDataType);
        txtDataType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                txtDataType.showDropDown();
            }
        });
        txtDataType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                //Check if the string has a ( and if so, set the cursor to be just after it so the user can enter the size
                int bracketPos = selectedItem.indexOf("(");
                if (bracketPos > 0)
                {
                    //Crashes on this line
                    ((AutoCompleteTextView)view).setSelection(bracketPos+1);
                }
            }
        });

        List<String> datatypes = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table_datatypes));
        datatypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datatypes);
        txtDataType.setAdapter(datatypeAdapter);
        rowViews.add(row);
        createTable.addView(row);
    }
```

I tried casting the view to AppCompatTextView but then this doesn't have the `setSelection()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `view` in `onItemClick()` is the `AppCompatTextView` that is clicked in the drop down box for the `AutoCompleteTextView`. That is why you can't cast it.

Since you have multiple `AutoCompleteTextViews`, use a focus change listener to capture which `AutoCompleteTextView` is being addressed by the user. You can then use that value to set the position of the cursor.

```
private AutoCompleteTextView textView;
private AutoCompleteTextView mAuto;

textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        mAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView) v;
    }
});

textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "<<<<onItemClicked");
        int bracketPos = textView.getText().toString().indexOf("(");
        if (bracketPos > 0) {
            mAuto.setSelection(bracketPos + 1);
        }
    }
});
```

I believe that the `AutoCompleteTextView` is already populated when this method is called, so you could just search for `(` within that field.

---

Here is a slightly different way. After

```
txtDataType = row.findViewById(R.id.txtDataType);
```

add

```
txtDataType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAutoView;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mAutoView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v;
        mAutoView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "<<<<onItemClicked");
                int bracketPos = mAutoView.getText().toString().indexOf("(");
                if (bracketPos > 0) {
                    mAutoView.setSelection(bracketPos + 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can delete your other listeners.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, that's what I had originally, before using the View from the OnItemClick. Because there's several controls on the layout, I believe it txtDataType will be referencing the latest element, so if I am trying to set the cursor position of the second control, it will be the last control that will be attempted and then crash as its then out of bounds as it has no input. I have a feeling I might have to roll my own version to do what I want I need

Comment: @Boardy What I posted does work in my small test and I have confirmed the error that you are getting. You will need to post additional info regarding `txtDateType` to look at a better solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'll double check but I believe it only works if there's 1 control, the addRow function is being called multiple times so there are several controls of the same type.

Comment: @Boardy I see now what you are saying. You will need a way to track back to the `AutoCompleteTextView` from the `View` that is passed in or capture the `AutoCompleteTextView` when it receives focus - something like that.

Comment: Ah yes, that's given me an idea, as the control is created I set a tag which is a counter and add it to an arraylist. Then I can get the tag from the view, and then get the corresponding control from the array list

Comment: @Boardy Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help that was exactly what I was after